# Excel VBA set named range as header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set named range that is N2:P3 named as "NorthHead" as center header. However with my code I get only cell N2 in header. What might be the problem?

```
Sub SetCenterHeader()
         ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = Range("NorthHead")
         ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some text in all of those cells, then just join them:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetCenterHeader()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim myRow As Range

    With Range("NorthHead") ' reference named range
        For Each myRow In .Rows ' loop through referenced range rows
            txt = txt & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myRow.Value)), " ") & vbLf ' update 'txt' with current row cells values joined and separated by a blank
        Next
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1) ' set CenterHeader with resulting 'txt' excluding last vblf character
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```